# Centre of mass as a function of distance

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, geometry

I have searched it on Google and also visited the HyperPhysics website to find out but all they seem to offer world centre of mass of continuous and uniformly bodies.My school textbooks are of no help either.
1. Is it possible to calculate the [centre of mass](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Center_of_mass) of a body in which the distribution of mass is non uniform?

2. Do we need to apply integration?
3. What happens if the mass varies linearly with the distance in a rod
   or as any other function of r in any regular body?

Comment: Have you done [the obvious Google search](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=calculate%20centre%20of%20mass) to see if you can find the answer for yourself?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it [shows insufficient prior research](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/5778/what-counts-as-sufficient-prior-research-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: @Karan do you have a textbook? It should be in there if it's calculus-based.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it takes integration. Take a small section of the rod ${\rm d}x$ with density $\rho(x)$ and cross sectional area $A(x)$.

The mass of the rod is $$ m = \int \limits_0^\ell \rho(x) A(x) {\rm d}x $$

The center of mass $x_C$ is defined as

$$ x_C = \frac{1}{m} \int \limits_0^\ell x \rho(x) A(x) {\rm d}x $$